# Pass Action<.., .., T > as Parameter without a predefined number of action parameters

Tags: c#, generic-programming

I have the following code:

```
public doSomething(List<Int64> data, Int64 counter){
    //Do something
}    

public doSomethingNext(List<Int64> data, String Something){
    //Do something next
}    

public static void Loop<T>(Action<T> action) {
        //Do something before
        action(T);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write the Loop method in such a generic way, that I can pass every method regardless of the parameters of the method. Something like this:

```
Loop(doSomething,....?);
Loop(doSomethingNext,...?);
```

@Edit 19:40  24-06-2015  More information

Sorry the 'action(T);' part generates the error that T is unknown. However I filled it in there because I do not know how to make this work.

When I use the following code it works with Linq:

```
//Method
public static void Loop(Action action) {
    //Do something before
    action();
    }
}

//Call
Loop(() => doSomething(data, counter));
```

However I am curious if it can also work without Linq? (With something like < T >)

(A side-question, is it possible to be able to access the parameters of the method in the Loop function?)

Comment: Using standard c# syntax - no. But you can do that via reflection, detect signature of the method and act accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda method when calling Loop to transform your method into an Action:

```
 Loop(t => doSomething(t, counter));

 Loop(t => doSomethingNext(t, Something));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have as the parameter a `Delegate`... like:

```
public static void Loop<T>(Delegate action) {
}
```

but then you would have to

```
action.DynamicInvoke(someparameters);
```

so use reflection to invoke it... and what parameters would you use?

---

Normally if the parameters are "fixed" and "chosen" by the caller, this problem is solved with [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application):

```
public static void Loop(Action action)
{
    action();
}
```

and you use it like:

```
Loop(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));
```

here `Console.WriteLine()` has one parameter, but it is fixed by the caller through the creation of another method (an anonymous method) with 0 parameters from which a delegate of type `Action` is created.

You don't need to remove all of the arguments from the delegate though:

```
public static void Loop<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    // generate some T value
    T value = GetValue<T>();

    // call action with a T parameter
    action(value);
}
```

and then:

```
Loop((int x) => Console.WriteLine("Some number: {0}", x));
```

In this case, `Console.WriteLine()` is using two parameters, of which one has been fixed (`"Some number: {0}"`) and one remains truly variable (`x`).

Comment: I suggest to remove Console.WriteLine for clarity.

Comment: @rudolf_franek Why?  What's the problem with it?  What would you suggest using instead?

Comment: @Servy that's not really partial application either, nothing is partially applied there (but it could in the purpose of "multiparameter" Action I agree); it's just use of high order function

Comment: @Sehnsucht The `Loop` method isn't doing any partial application.  It's expecting the caller to use partial application as necessary to conform to the delegate that it is expecting.

Comment: I suggest to remove Console.WriteLine for clarity. -> Why? -> because it adds complexity to the example that blurs the answer.. -> please see answer from @shf301

Comment: I mixed `curry(ing)` with `partial application`. Corrected. I do think that the `Console.WriteLine()` is a good method to call. I had to chose a function to use and I selected it. I could have selected other functions, but I wanted a function with a parameter that had a visible side effect.